# UIImageView disappears but not UILabel when cell is selcted

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uiimageview

I have a custom UITableview cell with a UILabel and a UIImageView when the cell but made in the storyboard and connected with IBOutlet, when the cell is selected the background of the image view changes to the selection color? How can I have the UIImageView's background color stay the same?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try call:

```
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone
```

in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

And (optionally) override:

```
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
```

swift:

```
override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool)
```

**Swift** Example usage:

```
override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    if selected {
        yourView.alpha = 0.5
    } else {
        yourView.alpha = 1.0
    }
}
```

You can also change your view's alpha inside `animateWithDuration` block:

```
override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, animations: {
        if selected {
            yourView.alpha = 0.5
        } else {
            yourView.alpha = 1.0
        }
    })
}
```

**Obj-C** example usage:

```
#import "YourTableViewCell.h"

@implementation YourTableViewCell

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];
    //your code
    // example: yourView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
}

- (void)setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setHighlighted:highlighted animated:YES];
    //your code
    // example: yourView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
}

@end
```

Comment: How and where do I call setSelected?

Comment: As you can see there is `override` keyword before function declaration. You don't have to call it. UITableView will call it for you. Just place this method in your UITableViewCell subclass.

Comment: I've added example usage.

Answer (score 0):

You can change you cell's imageView in `-didSelectRowAtIndexPath` of you `UITableView`

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
          //get the cell from the selected row.
          UITableViewCell *selectedCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]; 

         //change custom cell's imageView to desired backgroundColor
         selectedCell.imageView = [UIColor clearColor];
}
```

And don't forget to implement `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDatasource`

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be happening due to tableviewcell selection.
Just use the below code snippet

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    [tableview deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
```

This might help you. If not then please share the info of your implementation for this.

Answer (score 0):

you might have set the background color of the image view to clear color.